# unable to send UDP packets inside of eventEmitter within NodeJS

Tags: node.js, udp, eventemitter

I am new to EventEmitter and I was not able to find anything on the web with regard to my question (most likely because I am way off target).  I have an EventEmitter working currently.  I am writing out the events just fine via console.  However, if I try and send the data via UDP to a remote server inside the emitter, it is as if that code is completely ignored, no error message, no nothing, the code never gets in side the client.send part of the function. Thanks in advance.

```
var PORT = 1337;
var HOST = 'xxxx';
var dgram = require('dgram');
var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
const dump1090 = require('./node_modules/node-dump1090/build/Release/dump1090.node');
const NativeEmitter = dump1090.NativeEmitter;
const inherits = require('util').inherits;
inherits(NativeEmitter, EventEmitter);

const emitter = new NativeEmitter();

emitter.on('data', (evt) => {
    var mes = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(evt), 'utf8');
    console.log(mes);
    client.send(mes, 0, mes.length, PORT, HOST, function(err, bytes) {
        console.log('UDP message sent to ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
        if (err) throw err;
        client.close();
    });
})

emitter.callAndEmit();
```

Comment: Can you make it async? make it return a promise

Comment: Why are you closing the socket if there isn't an error?

Comment: I think more than likely I simply dont understand how emitters work, I am simply trying to forward the message to remote port, seems so simply, but it doesnt want to play